# Converting Dictionary<string, dynamic> to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm pretty new to C#. Currently I am working on some code left behind by someone else and it might have never worked before. There is a method that accepts two string values as parameters.

```
public void Update(string area, string value)
{
   //Perform operation
}
```

The above method was being called like this and this result in - "The best overloaded method match for..." error being thrown. The dynamic values can consist of bool, int and string.

```
public void UpdateAll(Dictionary<string, dynamic> values)
      {
         foreach (var entry in values)
         {
            Update(entry.Key, entry.Value);
         }
      }
```

My solution was to convert the Dictionary<string, dynamic> to Dictionary<string, string> within UpdateAll method first as shown below as I thought it will require the least amount of change. However I'm getting the error "Cannot convert type 'int' to 'string'" or "Cannot convert type 'bool' to 'string'"

```
public void UpdateAll(Dictionary<string, dynamic> values)
      {
         var convertedValues = values.ToDictionary(row => (string) row.Key, row => (string) row.Value);
         foreach (var entry in convertedValues)
         {
            Update(entry.Key, entry.Value);
         }
      }
```

What would be the best way to resolve and go about it?

Comment: Are you getting the errors at runtime? I believe the problem is related to the fact, that under `dynamic` any runtime type can be hidden, `int`, `bool`, whatever. If you want to convert it to `string`, just do this `entry.Value.ToString()`

Comment: You should avoid using `dynamic` unless absolutely necessary, unless the type is truly unknown (which is unlikely).

Comment: I guess it would depend on what Update method is doing and what the acceptable types of entry.Value can be. If you know these and what the expected 'Update' should be then you should be fine to validate against those types and restrict accordingly. As others have mentioned using 'dynamic' is risky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `dynamic` can be any type at runtime and you (and compiler) don't know the actual type until runtime. See this

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
values.Add("key1", 5);
values.Add("key2", true);
values.Add("key3", "value");
```

That code is compiled and executed nicely. The dictionary behaves similarly as this has `object` as its type argument for values.

Therefore when you iterate this dictionary, `entry.Value` might have different types for different elements of dictionary: `int`, `bool`, `string`, whatever. And when this has, for example, type `int`, the overload resolution process just can't find the method `Update(string, int)`, therefore the exception occurs.  You can fix this by simply converting it to string with a simple call `ToString()`. Hopefully all the types in .NET have `ToString` method, therefore it's pretty safe:

```
Update(entry.Key, entry.Value.ToString())
```

**But be careful**, `entry.Value` still can be `null`, so that it might be useful first to check against `null` and then convert it to `string`.

Another way of fixing this is to have overloads of `Update` method for different types which can be part of your dictionary. This is not very feasible if you don't really know what the dictionary might contain, but might be pretty good if you know the types for sure and they won't be extended too often. And of course if this is possible to write different versions of the `Update` method:

```
void Update(string area, string value) { ... }
void Update(string area, int value) { ... }
void Update(string area, bool value) { ... }
```

Also, I don't know your client code which calls `UpdateAll`, but you can also consider this dictionary to have an `object` type argument instead of `dynamic`. The behavior will be the same, but in the case of object you have a help from the compiler about `ToString` method.

```
void UpdateAll(Dictionary<string, object> values)
```

**Note** that this way of declaring the dictionary (with `object`) doesn't allow using the method overloads described above.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
        Update(entry.Key, entry.Value.ToString());
```

Be wary of interesting types that don't create an expected representation for ToString().  (eg classes will often just give you a hash value.)

If you just have base types you should be fine.